# Expected v-bind directive on complex <template> / v-for

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vue-component

I'm running into a strange issue with a complex loop I'm attempting within my component.

```
<template v-for="(scorecard, scorecardIndex) in scorecards">
    <template v-for="(property, propertyIndex) in properties">
        <!-- Primary player -->
        <tr v-if="scorecardIndex === 0"
            v-bind:key="propertyIndex"> // THIS LINE
        </tr>
    </template>

    <!-- Secondary players, should only show score -->
    <tr v-if="scorecardIndex > 0"
        v-bind:key="scorecardIndex">    
    </tr>
</template>
```

Where I'm setting `v-bind:key="propertyIndex"` I'm getting the following error within VSCode

> [vue/valid-v-for]
>   Expected 'v-bind:key' directive to use the variables which are defined by the 'v-for' directive.

The weird thing about this is that I don't actually get an error on my vue compiler, just within VSCode. This makes me think it has something to do directly with VSCode and not necessarily Vue itself.

Comment: It seems to be an eslint plugin issue. Do you use it ?

Comment: shouldn't the bind: key be in the same tag as the v-for? <template v-for... v-bind:key...> ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting this error from eslint which checks your code for possible errors and bad coding style.

When you use `v-for` on `<template>`, you need to make sure you define `key` on each top-level element within the `<template>`. This is because `<template>` is not an actual DOM element (within a Vue template) and so each element within it will be repeated at the same level in the DOM which is why `key` is required on each element at that DOM tree level.

You have a nested `<template>`, each using `v-for`, so it gets a bit more complicated. You need to make sure that the key of the first `<tr>` uses variables defined by *both* `v-for`s. Although in your specific case, you are using `v-if` to limit the element being created to only the first row, so eslint is being too pedantic here. You can silence the warning like this:

```vue
<!-- eslint-disable-next-line vue/valid-v-for -->
<tr v-if="scorecardIndex === 0"
    v-bind:key="propertyIndex">
</tr>
```

But I think you have the order around the wrong way. It makes more sense to first check if it is the first row and *then* repeat a bunch of `<tr>`s, instead of the other way around:

```vue
<template v-if="scorecardIndex === 0">
    <!-- Primary player -->
    <tr v-for="(property, propertyIndex) in properties"
        v-bind:key="propertyIndex">
    </tr>
</template>
```

Lastly, you will get some duplicate key warnings because both sets of `<tr>`s will use keys 0, 1, 2, and so on. Maybe prefix them:

```vue
<template v-for="(scorecard, scorecardIndex) in scorecards">
    <template v-if="scorecardIndex === 0">
        <!-- Primary player -->
        <tr v-for="(property, propertyIndex) in properties"
            v-bind:key="'primary-' + propertyIndex">
        </tr>
    </template>

    <!-- Secondary players, should only show score -->
    <tr v-if="scorecardIndex > 0"
        v-bind:key="'secondary-' + scorecardIndex">    
    </tr>
</template>
```